# Почему не работает консольный ввод в switch (JAVA)

Tags: java, ввод, switch

```
Не работает данная строка кода с вводом string и последующий записью этого значения в arraylist. Сама программ выводит 
Выберите действие:
 1-добавить студента
 2- удалить студента
 3-заменить студента
 4-найти номер студента из списка  
1
Добавьте студента

[]
 ----
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> student_list = new ArrayList<String>();


        System.out.println("Выберите действие:");
        System.out.println(" 1-добавить студента\n 2- удалить студента\n 3-заменить студента\n 4-найти номер студента из списка  ");

        int tag_name = in.nextInt();



        switch (tag_name){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Добавьте студента");
                student_list.add(in.nextLine());
                break;

        }

        System.out.println(student_list);
    }
```

Comment: Не работает команда ввода в условии switch, выводится Добавьте студента а затем компилятор  пропускает строку ввода.

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос полностью и добавьте нужную информацию не в комментарии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама проблема заключается в том, что `scan.nextInt()` считывает не всю строку, а лишь число, оставляя в буфере `\n`, который и принимает следующий `scan.nextLine()`. Чтобы решить эту проблему, можно, например вызвать холостой `scan.nextLine()` перед основным рабочим телом Вашей программы. Это уберет из буфера перенос строки и далее все заработает так, как того бы хотелось.